# Show file updates in a browser

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

My goal is to update the web page whenever I edit and save the file on the localhost, and instantly its content appears updated to a page.

I'm using socket.io to handle this task. But I'm facing a problem on the client side.  The server is detecting changes to the file and posting console log messages as I would expect.

Server code:

```
var PORT = 8082;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(PORT);
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("dir", __dirname);

const logfile = 'jsondata.json';

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.emit('connected', { accept: true});

    console.log("Trying to send the content to a client...");
    console.log("dir", __dirname);

    fs.watch(logfile, function(event, filename) {
        console.log("Event:", event);

        if (event == "change") {
            fs.readFile(__dirname + "/jsondata.json", "UTF-8", function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                socket.emit("fileChanged", data );
                console.log("Content:", data);
            })
        }

    });

});

console.log("Application has started! Port: " + PORT);
```

A cycle of activity on the NodeJS console looks like this:

```
Application has started! Port: 8082    
Connected!
Trying to send the content to a client...
dir C:\Users\JavaScript\Project
Event: change
Content: {"newitem": 57, "address": 141414}
```

Which correctly corresponds to the JSON written into the file.

Client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            .dataFile {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                width: 900px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("Try to logon...");
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8082');

            socket.on("connected", function(data) {
                console.log("Connected User?", data.accept);
            });

            var requestFile = socket.on("fileChanged", function(data) {
                $("#dataFile").html(data + "<br/>");
                console.log(data);
            });

            setInterval(requestFile, 200);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 style="font: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
            File updated:
        </h3>
        <div id="dataFile">

        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

The browser's console log is a little more cryptic:

```
Try to logon... index.html:17:13
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
note: [ opened at line 29, column 0

Connected User? true index.html:21:17
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
note: [ opened at line 29, column 0
```

The issue shown above is puzzling me.  I'm not sure where the square bracket issue is coming from since I don't have any in my code.

**** Updated code to correct socket handler name issue ****

Comment: What is the `setInterval` statement supposed to do ?

Comment: Monitor for the fileChanged event every 200 ms and post an update when found.

Comment: It is not doing that, with `socket.on` you set a listener, that needs to be done only once. Also, `requestFile` will be a `socket` not a function.

Comment: Well, that solved it coupled with @Tappyy 's response.  Commenting out the setInterval did the trick.  Odd because I found that code elsewhere...  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server code you are using `socket.emit("receiveFile", data)` but on your client you are using `socket.on("requestFile", (function(data) ... )`

Your socket is emitting and listening for 2 different events... To fix, rename `receiveFile` and `requestFile` to be the same name - something like `fileChanged`.

That way, your server will be emitting a `fileChanged` event and your client will be listening.

For more, check out the socket.io docs on [Sending and Receiving Events](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-receiving-events)

Comment: Good catch. I thought I fixed that.  I'm still getting the same error, however.  I'll update my code above.

Comment: This did fix my data transfer issue.  I just still get the square bracket issue.

Comment: Do you have any brackets inside the data you are returning?

Comment: Only curly brackets (It's a JSON that I'm treating as a string)